Factoring semiprimes via sum of two squares?
The following thoughts came into my head after watching Grant Sanderson's JBPM award lecture here, in which he discusses the fact that we can quickly factor 3599 by noticing it can be written as (60-1)(60+1). This is a nice trick for mental arithmetic, but also can be computed in one's head much faster than checking all of the factors of 3599. It struck me that I don't know the complexity of determining whether a number can be written as the difference of two primes, and I also do not know what percentage of semiprimes can be written as a difference of squares. Apologies if this question is obvious to an expert in the area!
Formally:
Let S be the set of semiprimes, $S = \{ mn : m,n \in Prime\}$, and let D be the set of numbers that can be written as the difference of squares, not counting adjacent squares $D = \{ a^2 - b^2 : a, b\in \mathbb{N} \,,a-b\neq1\}$.
For any number $q \in S$, we have that $q = a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$. If $(a-b) \neq 1$ this is a prime factorization.
Finding values for $a^2, b^2$ is sufficient to find the prime factorization of q.
From this observation, we have that factoring any number $q \in S \cap D$ reduces to the problem of finding the squares whose difference is $q$.
I don't know much about this area of number theory, and so my immediate follow up questions are:

Is there a fast algorithm for determining whether a number can be written as the difference of two squares (besides the a-b case). I know the time complexity of factoring is exponential in input length, what do we know about difference of two squares?

What is the density of $D$ within $S$?


I'm thinking that if there is some better-than-exponential algorithm, and a high density for 2), there could be some faster test for factorization that works on a subset of semiprimes.

This does not look like a research-level question. Clearly, a natural number can be written as $a^2-b^2$ with $a-b\ne1$ iff it can be written as a nontrivial product of two integers of the same parity, which holds iff it is either odd composite or divisible by $4$.

You want to read up on the quadratic sieve.

Every positive integer that is not twice an odd number can be written as a difference of two squares. Deciding whether a given odd number $n$ can be written as $a^2-b^2$ other than with $a=(n+1)/2$ and $b=(n-1)/2$ is exactly as difficult as determining whether $n$ is prime. Finding such $a,b$ is exactly as difficult as factoring $n$. The method is attributed to Fermat, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

What is faster, checking if $n$ can be written as $a^2-b^2$ or checking if $n$ can be divided by $2, 3, 5, 7, 11,$ ...  I don't know. But generally, when we want to check if a specific number is prime, this specific number is not a random number, it has been generated with some process that garantee that this number will not be a multiple of $2, 3, 5, 7$...  (small primes). So, depending of the context, testing if $a^2-n$ is a perfect square may be more efficient, or not.

This is also why the semiprimes used in cryptography must satisfy various conditions. Neither prime factor is small, so that trial division cannot find it in any reasonable time. Fermat's difference of squares method is like trial division but starting at the other end. To stop that from working, the prime factors must not be too close together (so the $b$ in $a^2-b^2$ is too large to find). There are other conditions that are imposed to thwart other known methods. Hopefully all essentially brute force methods would take too long to hit upon the factors.

Checking whether $n$ can be written as $a^2-b^2$ is trivial and instantaneous. It's finding $a$ and $b$ that's hard. For large numbers $n$, with a very thin set of exceptions, trial division and difference of squares are both horrendous factorization techniques, and not of any practical use. If you really need to factor humungous numbers, it's time to learn about the quadratic sieve, the number field sieve, the elliptic curve method, and other advanced procedures.

@GerryMyerson, what is the technique for checking if n can be written as the difference of two squares?
Also, do you have references for the fact that there is no known efficient way to find a, b? I feel like perspective shifts like this are useful... either there is a fast way to approach this problem or we prove it is just as hard as factoring and learn a bit more about the nature of finding differences of squares...

Please keep up, weissguy – I wrote in an earlier comment in this thread, "Every positive integer that is not twice an odd number can be written as a difference of two squares." Finding $a,b$ is computationally equivalent to factoring $n$. If you have $a$ and $b$ (with $|a-b|\ne1$), you have a factorization of $n$, and if you have a factorization of $n$, you have $a$ and $b$. That proves finding (nontrivial) $a,b$ is just as hard as factoring $n$.

Ah, makes sense. Thank you!

To answer question 2 (question 1 has been dispatched in the comments), all the odd semiprimes are in $D$, and the even semiprimes have zero density in the set of all semiprimes, so the required density is $1$.
